# PHPMailer populating emails from result of query

Tags: php, arrays, phpmailer

I'm trying to populate the email addresses in PHPMailer from an array returned by a query.

```
$query = 'SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.email FROM users u INNER JOIN locations l ON (u.location_id = l.id) WHERE district_id = 8 GROUP BY id ORDER BY first_name, last_name ASC';

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (!result) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($result));
}

$recipients = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

This gives me a result such as:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [first_name] => Jon [last_name] => Smith [email] => jon@domain.com )
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [first_name] => Dave [last_name] => Virk [email] => dave@domain.com )
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [first_name] => Chris [last_name] => West [email] => chris@domain.com )
)
```

But being new to working with arrays like this I'm not sure how to extract the name and email of each user for PHPMailer.

I read an example that did something like this:

```
foreach($recipients as $email => $name) {
   $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
}
```

How would I adapt this?

Comment: Just a minor comment: You need to pass the db link (`$connection`) to `mysqli_error()`, not `$result` (which is `FALSE` if it fails).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it would be:

```
foreach($results as $row) {
    $mail->AddAddress($row['email'], $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name']);
}
```

You need to refer the key values inside square brackets `[]`

Comment: This seems to work, but I tested it using `echo $row['email'] . ' ' . $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'];` and it gave me 4 of each email & name. Does this work differently with echo?

Comment: @Mike No, it should work the same way with `echo` like **[in here](https://eval.in/138725)**